# Convert PDF files to images with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

Can someone give me an example on how to use Apache PDFBox to convert a PDF file in different images (one for each page of the PDF)?

Comment: Can it be in only one image ?

Answer (score 135):

Solution for 1.8.* versions:

```java
PDDocument document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(pdfFilename), null);
List<PDPage> pdPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
int page = 0;
for (PDPage pdPage : pdPages)
{ 
    ++page;
    BufferedImage bim = pdPage.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300);
    ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, pdfFilename + "-" + page + ".png", 300);
}
document.close();
```

Don't forget to read the [1.8 dependencies page](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html) before doing your build.

Solution for the 2.0 version:

```java
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilename));
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
{ 
    BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);

    // suffix in filename will be used as the file format
    ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, pdfFilename + "-" + (page+1) + ".png", 300);
}
document.close();
```

Solution for the 3.0 versions:

```
PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(new File(pdfFilename));
```

(the rest is like in 2.0)

The ImageIOUtil class is in a separate download / artifact (pdf-tools). Read the [2.0 dependencies page](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html) before doing your build, you'll need extra jar files for PDFs with jbig2 images, for saving to tiff images, and reading of encrypted files.

Make sure you have logging enabled and are using the latest version of whatever JDK version prefer, i.e. if you are using jdk8, then don't use version 1.8.0_5, use 1.8.0_391 or whatever is the latest at the time you're reading this text. Early jdk versions were very slow.

Comment: For future readers of this Q&A you might also want to post a solution for 2.x (unless the API change in that respect has not yet stabilized, that is).

Comment: If the PDF has graphics on it this doesn't seem to include them. It may also lose many graphical details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523688/pdfbox-problem-with-converting-pdf-page-into-image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332791/converting-pdf-to-image-with-proper-formatting

Comment: Note that in order to use ImageIOUtil in 2.0 you will need to add a dependency on pdfbox-tools.

Comment: Great example! Thanks. Two remarks though:

 * in the 2.0 version, `BufferedImage bim = ` is missing in the fifth line

 * Notice that "300" is the zoom level and not (as I assumed) a dpi value or something. It wasn't before I got tons of OutOfMemory exceptions that I thought to check the API!

Comment: @colouredmirrorball thanks re the code mistake; the 300 is a zoom value that ensures a dpi quality :-)

Comment: What exactly is the dependency you have to add for ImageIOUtil when using PDFBox 2.0?

Comment: @Aeseir you need pdfbox-tools. Plus the levigo jbig2 decoder, and jai_imageio.jar.

Comment: Thanks bud, found out they migrated the tools to a different jar.

Comment: renderImageWithDPI is taking more than 2-3 mins for a few colored documents, I am using openjdk 8.0.202. Please help.

Comment: Please create an issue in the pdfbox JIRA issue tracker. Include the file.

Comment: This is happening only in a multithreaded application although only single thread is accessing PDFBox. Test application works fine, takes less than 1 secs for same page.

Comment: Then I can't tell… try creating a test scenario that reproduces the problem. And then open a JIRA issue.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr do you know if the Active content is executed or ignored with this conversion?

Comment: @dieter Javascript is ignored (assuming that this was the question).

Answer (score 21):

I tried it today with PdfBox 2.0.15.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;


public static void PDFtoJPG (String in, String out) throws Exception
{
    PDDocument pd = PDDocument.load (new File (in));
    PDFRenderer pr = new PDFRenderer (pd);
    BufferedImage bi = pr.renderImageWithDPI (0, 300);
    ImageIO.write (bi, "JPEG", new File (out)); 
}
```

Comment: works like a charm, just one thing. If the pdf document has more than one page use: pd.getNumberOfPages() to do a loop for every page.

Comment: This gives me java heap space what would be the reason ?

Comment: @GhostDede Did you play around with the DPI value? Maybe lowering solves your problem.

Comment: Yes lowering DPI value solves my problem but  I need 500 DPI

Comment: @GhostDede pretty sure you need to increase the java heap space. 500 DPI needs more heap than 300 DPI.

Answer (score 4):

```java
public class PDFtoJPGConverter {

    public List<File> convertPdfToImage(File file, String destination) throws Exception {

    File destinationFile = new File(destination);

    if (!destinationFile.exists()) {
        destinationFile.mkdir();
        System.out.println("DESTINATION FOLDER CREATED -> " + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }else if(destinationFile.exists()){
        System.out.println("DESTINATION FOLDER ALLREADY CREATED!!!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("DESTINATION FOLDER NOT CREATED!!!");
    }

    if (file.exists()) {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
        PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(doc);
        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();

        String fileName = file.getName().replace(".pdf", "");
        System.out.println("CONVERTER START.....");

        for (int i = 0; i < doc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        // default image files path: original file path
        // if necessary, file.getParent() + "/" => another path
        File fileTemp = new File(destination + fileName + "_" + i + ".jpg"); // jpg or png
        BufferedImage image = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(i, 200);
        // 200 is sample dots per inch.
        // if necessary, change 200 into another integer.
        ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", fileTemp); // JPEG or PNG
        fileList.add(fileTemp);
        }
        doc.close();
        System.out.println("CONVERTER STOPTED.....");
        System.out.println("IMAGE SAVED AT -> " + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
        return fileList;
    } else {
        System.err.println(file.getName() + " FILE DOES NOT EXIST");
    }
    return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        PDFtoJPGConverter converter = new PDFtoJPGConverter();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your destination folder where save image \n");
        // Destination = D:/PPL/;
        String destination = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your selected pdf files name with source folder \n");
        String sourcePathWithFileName = sc.nextLine();
        // Source Path = D:/PDF/ant.pdf,D:/PDF/abc.pdf,D:/PDF/xyz.pdf
        if (sourcePathWithFileName != null || sourcePathWithFileName != "") {
        String[] files = sourcePathWithFileName.split(",");
        for (String file : files) {
            File pdf = new File(file);
            System.out.print("FILE:>> "+ pdf);
            converter.convertPdfToImage(pdf, destination);
        }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

====================================

Here i am use Apache pdfbox-2.0.8 , commons-logging-1.2 and fontbox-2.0.8 Library

HAPPY CODING :)

Answer (score 2):

w/o any extra dependencies you can just use the `PDFToImage` class already included in `PDFBox`.

Kotlin:

`PDFToImage.main(arrayOf<String>("-outputPrefix", "newImgFilenamePrefix", existingPdfFilename))`

other config opts: https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.8/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/PDFToImage.html

Comment: There will be dependencies. You'll see it when having a PDF with restricted rights or which has JPEG 2000 images or JBIG2 images.

Comment: There “will be dependencies” in *that* case. For my use case we are turning pdfs we create into imgs so there isn’t the issue of restricted rights or those different img kinds.

Comment: Such images are IN the PDFs. Example: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12865265/jbig2.pdf You're only safe if you know in advance that your input PDFs don't have these types of images inside them.

Comment: The link with javadoc does not describe other options (in fact it does not describe any). At the moment one can use this mirrored source code to review options: https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/PDFToImage.java

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Pdf2Image {

    public String convertPdf2Img(String fileInput, Path path) {
        String destDir = "";
        try {
            String destinationDir = path.toString();
            File sourceFile = new File(fileInput);
            File destinationFile = new File(destinationDir);

            if (!destinationFile.exists()) {
                destinationFile.mkdir();
                System.out.println("Folder Created -> " + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            if (sourceFile.exists()) {
                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceFile);
                PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

                String fileName = sourceFile.getName().replace(".pdf", "");

                // int pageNumber = 0;

                // for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
                for (int pageNumber = 0; pageNumber < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++pageNumber) {
                    BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImage(pageNumber);

                    destDir = destinationDir + File.separator + fileName + "_" + pageNumber + ".png";

                    ImageIO.write(bim, "png", new File(destDir));
                }

                document.close();

                System.out.println("Image saved at -> " + destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                System.err.println(sourceFile.getName() + " File does not exist");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return destDir;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of your solution compared with all the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

Just adding the following snippet for the new Apache pdfbox version 3 (3.0.0-RC1)

```
        try(PDDocument pddDoc =  Loader.loadPDF(docFile) ){
            PDFRenderer pr = new PDFRenderer (pddDoc );
            BufferedImage backImage = pr.renderImage(0);
        } catch (IOException  e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Notes

- version 3 (3.0.0-RC1) works with GraalVM and the new just released [Liberica Native Image Kit](https://bell-sw.com/announcements/2022/08/05/liberica-native-image-kit-22-2-0-and-21-3-3-builds-are-out/) allows for awt on Linux/Windows/Mac
- `PDDocument.load` ect replaced by new `org.apache.pdfbox.Loader` class

Answer (score 0):

Here is part of my code to convert a pdf, from a multipart file, to jpg thumbnail. I'm saving the image as a base64 string. Pdfbox 2.0.21 version was used.

```
private static String generatePdfThumbnail(byte[] imageInBytesArray) throws IOException {
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(imageInBytesArray);
    PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = renderer.renderImage(0);
    Graphics2D bufImageGraphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    bufImageGraphics.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    boolean foundWriter = ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", baos);
    byte[] fileContent = null;
    if (!foundWriter) {
      return "";
    }

    fileContent = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
  }
```