# Pdfbox pdf viewer code

Tags: java, swing, pdfbox

I need to create a java desktop application, the goal is to display documents(doc,xls,pdf) with free libraries.

I only could display *.ods documents with jOpenDocument and that's all that i got by the moment.

I was viewing pdfbox library, but i cannot find a single exemple anywhere to display the pdf inside a java application.

Can you help me please?

Comment: See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326562/apache-pdfbox-convert-pdf-to-images and/or look at the source code for PDFReader

Comment: I see your question was put on hold (I didn't complain). I suggest you try the link I posted and the answer that already exist, write some code, then delete your question and write a new one that deals with whatever is still unclear. Leave out doc, ods and xls from the question, it isn't relevant for the PDF question.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to add your application's components to an [`org.apache.pdfbox.PDFReader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.4/org/apache/pdfbox/PDFReader.java), which extends `JFrame` without modifying the default layout manager, `BorderLayout`. As shown in `initComponents()`, `BorderLayout.CENTER` and `BorderLayout.SOUTH` are occupied by the document and status panel, respectively, but you can add your application's containers to the remaining layout regions.

Alternatively, adapt the components and actions shown in `initComponents()` to your own application.