# Squares/dots/blank as output while copying and pasting the text manually from PDF

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to extract text from PDF. First i tried with PDFBox. In output, I have found that some part of text was missing and on eclipse console I got the following warnings

**No Unicode mapping for CID+49 (49) in font Helvetica**

I wanted to know that what does above warning mean. I googled to know the meaning. But still i am not clear.It would be very helpful if someone provides a clear explanation.

For the same PDF,I got squares or dots shapes when I copied and pasted the text from PDF manually.I am wondering why this has happen. Please explain.

Comment: see the comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324398/issue-with-reading-some-unicode-characters-out-of-a-pdf-using-pdfbox

Comment: Essentially the information in the pdf concerning the font in question is too deficient for text extraction unless based on ocr.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper` package which have a method that can return all the text available in your pdf document automatically. the `String getText(PDDocument doc)` method can help you greatly . follow this link to go through the API  [PDF TextStripper](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/text/PDFTextStripper.html) . hope it will help

Comment: Yeah.I tried. From that approach only, I missed some part of the text in the final output.

Comment: This answer isn't helpful, he used PDFTextStripper, obviously.

Comment: may be you should try going deeper into the Api for something that can help you better