# Render/view a pdf with the use of a library like pdfbox/itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I'm looking into adding pdf-functionality in my own little software project but I'm unsure how to go around it by using such libraries as above.

Comment: there is a documentation

Comment: Do like everyone else, and read the books: https://developers.itextpdf.com/books

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326562/apache-pdfbox-convert-pdf-to-images

Answer (score 1):

With iText and PDFbox you can create and edit pdf files in a programmatic way, but to render/view a pdf, you need a different kind of library, something like JPedal.

That being said, "shopping list" questions are not allowed on Stack Overflow (and still you got an answer) because they attract low quality answers.