# How to remove blank pdf pages that has been scanned. I am using java and apache pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Please give advice on how to remove blank pdf pages that have been scanned?  I am using java and apache pdfbox.  I planned to compare blank and filled pages by size, but I do not know how to determine the size of the PDPage object in bytes.

Comment: You could render the PDF to images and then save this image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326562/ However this is not a perfect method. In some rare cases, a seemingly small page can have a small content, e.g. a stamp. One solution would be to make an additional manual check.

Comment: Also, the size thing only works nicely for b/w scans. So render to b/w images and save these.

Comment: Thanks, Tilman Hausherr. Your answer from another question also helped me a lot.