# How to split PDF with PDFBox after random number of pages?

Tags: java, split, pdfbox

I want to split a big PDF document with a specific criteria. Each page has the following header:

[image: PDF Header]

The code (in the PDF Header image is 000084292) can change after a random number of pages (I can have a new code after 1 page or maybe 3 or 10 ...). So everytime I found a new code in the header, I must create a new file with file name = code (for example: if my current code is 000084292 when I find the code 000084345, I must create the file 000084292.pdf, keep reading the original PDF document, if I find the code 000087209, I must create the file 000084345.pdf ....).

Comment: This is a scanned PDF, so first convert to images (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326562/ ), then use ZXing to get the barcode. To create new PDFs, either use the splitter class, or create a new PDF and add from the existing PDF with addPage().

Comment: If scanning problems like at the left side can also occur in the rest of the header, be prepared to also be confronted with unreadable barcodes you have to process separately.

Comment: Hi sorry, you're right .. I forgot the previous steps of my program:
1. The customer send me the PDF file, this file is an image
2. Convert the file in a readable format (with OCR programs)
3. Read PDF with Java and split it by the code

Normally the code is readable, but I know sometimes not (so I also need to manage this case).

I hope is more clear now..

Comment: If it is an OCRed PDF, then extract the text and find out whether there is a reliable way to get these barcodes (e.g. with regular expressions)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any control on the conversion Image to Text. If there is a method to convert the Image to Text from Java maybe I can directly split the file, but there is not. So I must work directly on the PDF file (text converted)

Comment: PDFBox can do text extraction (not OCR. I mean the text that is in the PDF after an OCR). Look for "ExtractTextSimple.java" in the source code download. Or run the ExtractText command line application.

Comment: Sorry for my english, maybe I can't explain the problem. I already have a readable PDF (so with my Java program I can read the content). But when, during the reading of the file, I find a new code (in the header of the document) I need to split. But as I know the split function works only with pages or after a certain number of pages. I don't know when I must split because the code can be different after one page or two or 10 (I don't know)..

Comment: If you know that pages 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14 are part of a sequence, then you get call PDPage.get() on these and call addPage() to a new PDDocument object.